# Bootstrap 3 2 Column Full Height Fixed Header and Footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

I'm having issues trying to make a 3 column full height layout work, but with a fixed nav, and fixed footer.

I can get the basics to work, 2 columns, with fixed nav and footer, but when I attempt to enable full height on the columns it tends to break completely.

On some attempts to resolve this the content disappears under the footer, and spills out below it. Other times when you resize the browser to test responsive elements, the footer sticks to the content pain when scrolling up the content, and not the bottom of the browser.

Is there any way to achieve this on a responsive framework? Or is it easier just to re-jig the design, or even fake full height, say by using a positioned repeating background. But then again that wouldn't be responsive either.

I've spent over 2-3 hours on this, so I'm throwing myself on the mercy of someone with better front end skills than I. Help!

Comment: What do you mean by "full height" columns?

Comment: Full page height, obviously minus the header (60px) and footer (60px) which is fixed position using position: absolute. If I give the body a height of 100%, it breaks the footer. But the html is already set at position: relative min-height: 100% which works for the footer.